# Какие технологии используются для разработки десктопных приложений

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, desktop

Я последние пол года увлекаюсь C#, правда умею в нем не много, делал декстоп приложение для планирования транспорта и заказов для суточной отгрузки товаров в магазины сети используя бд MS SQL, ну и писал под нее отчеты в reportviewer. И чем больше я увлекаюсь программированием, тем больше у меня вопросов, касательного того в правильном ли я направлении, так как подсказать не кому, сенсеев вокруг нет. Рассматривал всякого рода курсы, но у меня создалось впечатления что учителя переписывают видео уроки с Youtube и пересказывают их, причем в большинстве случаев даже не понимая о чем говорят, и как правило одна "вода" и только теория, ни примеров ни практики. Делал приложение я в WinForms, знаю что технология старая и не поддерживается MS. Я новичок в программировании, и перед тем как задать тут вопрос - я гуглил, но не нашел внятного ответа. На каком языке и используя какие технологии в современном мире пишутся десктопные приложения? Знаю что WPF новее WinForms, но читал некоторые статьи что увлекаться им тоже уже нет смысла, так как он тоже не развивается и не поддерживается. Так на чем писать декстопы на Java или на Pyton и пишутся ли они вообще на этих языках, возможно C++, прошу подсказать без `using(тролинг тр = new тролинг())`?

Comment: WPF не поддерживается? о_О Не знал, нужно срочно менять специализацию. Хорошо, что вы сказали.

Comment: Десктопные приложения можно и на ассемблере писать. Какова цель данного вопроса? Что конкретно хотите выяснить и для какой цели?

Comment: Можете глянуть в сторону JavaScript. electron.atom.io например. Да и вообще много подобных ему.

Comment: .net прекрасная платформа и на ней всегда есть работа, если вы достойный специалист. Так что, если она Вам нравится и вам не нужна кроссплатформенность продолжайте ёё изучать. P.S WPF поддерживается ни хуже конкурентов. Может вы про Silverlight читали?

Comment: @koks_rs пост был про WPF и Silverlight. Спасибо за ваш комментарий, буду осваивать WPF.

Comment: Кроссплатформенность есть, в чём проблема? На какой платформе не бежит Mono?

Comment: @Winteriscoming какого именно ответа вы ожидаете? списка технологий и языков?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам важно осознать, для начала, что уметь программировать и пишу программ на *имя-языка*. Это разные вещи. Потому, на мой взгляд, не надо распыляться или метаться.
C# в принципе пойдет (хотя лично я его недолюбливаю), достаточно много его используют в разработке прикладных приложений. Главное научитесь программировать. Беда языков тип C# позволяют самоучке не заглядывать "под капот" - как итог вроде и программа работает, а программист "не ахти".

Научитесь хорошо программировать, понимать алгоритмы... Там будет все равно какой язык. Вот там уже надо держать нос по ветру. Причем отслеживать вам самому свою личную ситуацию.

Лично я изучал просто чтоб изучить, только Basic (в 87 году). Потом были Turbo Pascal, Asm,Delphi, C++, PHP, Javascript..... И все они были освоены, по большому счету, "под проект". Просто на определенном этапе я видел, что лично я получу в данной ситуации больше в такой то нише.

В итоге: предпочитаемый C++ (на нем и десктопные кроссплатформенный писал и системные). С его "помощью" получал хороший доход пока кризис в Европе в 2008 не начался. Сейчас, так сложилось, хороший доход получаю программируя на PHP и JavaScript :)....

Т.е. не надо подбирать языка "так в принципе на будущее".... Не прыгайте. Пусть будет C#.Главное разберитесь как можно глубже... А там может вас пригласят в компанию с хорошей зарплатой на брейнфак  писать :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш совет, я начал с PHP, правда не умею его использовать как ООП, верней не ставил перед собой такую цель научится, а так в принципе еще не сталкивался с тем чего не смог реализовать на нем в сайтах. C#, в частности winforms, начал осваивать из за надобности на работе.

Comment: Беда C в том, что он не позволяет заглядывать под ассемблерный капот. Беда машинного кода в том, что он не позволяет заглядывать под капот процессора и управлять каждым транзистором вручную. Беда транзисторов в том, что они не дают возможность тонкого управления распределением заряда. Беда электронов в том, что мы не можем управлять позициями кварков в них.

Comment: @Winteriscoming вы вроде бы задали вполне конкретный вопрос - а отметили как принятый "совет", который не отвечает на ваш вопрос вообще никак (хотя как совет он вполне хорош)

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить от себя что в наши дни имея базу .net можно стабильно обеспечить себя работой в силу того что можно творить в очень многих сферах, веб, бизнес, десктоп, мобайл(да еще и кроссплатформенно), игры в конце концов :) мало сфер которые не охватывал бы .net

Comment: @VlaD, естественно есть разумные пределы, но согласитесь "программист" (для примера) уверенно размещающий на форме поле ввода, и  не понимающий что он использует ООП, и вообще что такое ООП. "Смотрится" довольно таки грустно. Мне приходилось с такими сталкиваться, в свою бы команду не взял.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр: Ну да, но вы говорите, наверное, о каком-то графическом фреймворке, типа WinForms? Потому что само программирование на C# вполне себе позволяет понять, что происходит — в рамках абстракций языка, которые, кстати, достаточно похожи на абстракции C++. Из кардинальных различий я навскидку назову лишь недоступность адресной арифметики и недетерминистическую деаллокацию.

Comment: @VladD не. Конечно же тут дело не в языке как таковом. Взять Builder С++ и будет то же самое. На мой взгляд это самая распространенная ошибка в самообучении: получаешь быстрый и красивый результат, забывая о базе. Взять Studio и С++ там с ходу, правда я последний раз им пользовался в 2005, там редактор форм еще найти надо :). А если взять (если речь о Windows) CodeBlock + MinGW - то тут базу точно придется изучить сначала.... 
В PHP вообще (если сразу не на фреймворки бросаться) придется все постигать.... Правда тут уже другие "проблемы" :D

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр: Ну, без основ можно разве что набросать простейшую формочку. Как только нужно что-то осмысленное (ну или просто приложение командной строки, или бекенд-библиокека), нужно понимать, что делается в коде.